# How to know the version of perl6/raku I am running?

Tags: raku, rakudo

Trying the `-v` switch, I get the parrot svn revision:

```
$ perl6 -v
This compiler is built with the Parrot Compiler Toolkit, parrot revision 45822.
```

but how do I know the **rakudo version**, either a `vx.xx` or `{some-git-hash}`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you can't know :(

There's a patch for that in RT that awaits review: http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=73148 but so far it hasn't been applied yet.

Update: With a sufficiently new Rakudo, you get:

```
$ perl6 -v

This is Rakudo Perl 6, version 2010.06-212-g1086ff8

Copyright 2008-2010, The Perl Foundation
```

Where the thing after "version" is the `git describe` output.

Answer (score 7):

The special variable `$*PERL` may provide the hint

```
> $*PERL.compiler
rakudo (2018.04.1)

> $*PERL.compiler.^attributes                                                                                                                                                                                     
(Str $!id Str $!release Str $!build-date Str $!codename Str $!name Str $!auth Version $!version Blob $!signature Str $!desc)

> $*PERL.compiler.^methods'                                                                                                                                                                                            
(BUILD build-date verbose-config Str gist id release codename name auth version signature desc BUILDALL) 

> $*PERL.compiler.name                                                                                                                                                                                       
rakudo

> $*PERL.compiler.version                                                                                                                                                                                       
v2018.04.1 

> $*PERL.compiler.auth                         
The Perl Foundation  

> $*PERL.compiler.build-date  # This being the date it was built on my machine                                                                                                                                                                                    
2018-05-18T21:59:11Z 

> $*PERL.compiler.verbose-config
...
```

Answer (score 4):

perl6 -v now works. It provides the last monthly release, the number of commits since then, and the git hash.